# simplify expression with variable in denominator

Tags: linear-algebra

If I have an expression like this:

$3 - {\frac{48}{x^2}} = 0$

I should first rearrange it to this:

${\frac{3 -48}{x^2} = 0}$

In the example I am using this from, it is then simplified to:

${\frac{3x^2 -48}{x^2} = 0}$

And then:

$3x^2 -48 = 0$

I do not understand the last 2 steps.  I thought you would have to apply $x^2$ to both terms in the numerator, i.e. ${\frac{3x^2 -48x^2}{x^2}} = 0$.

Also How does $x^2$ get cancelled out this way when $x^2$ only appears in part of the term of the expression when it is like this:

${\frac{3x^2 -48}{x^2}} = 0$

I don't get how $x^2$ is cancelled out when it only appears on part of the term in the numerator.

Comment: Could it be that you are trying to find out when $f^\prime(x)=0$? If so, that will happen when the numerator is 0. That is, $f^\prime(x)=0$ when $3x^2-48=0$ but $f^\prime(x)\ne3x^2-48$.

Comment: Is your question about how to get that $3-\frac{48}{x^2}=\frac{3x^2-48}{x^2}$?

Comment: Yes that is the first part of my question and also how can $x^2$ be cancelled out when it only appears in one term of ${\frac{3x^2 -48}{x^2} = 0}$

Comment: @dagda1 Try multiplying both sides of the expression mathlove wrote with $x^2$; they are then in the same form and it's obvious that they are equal.

Answer (score 0):

$3-{48\over x^2} \ne {3-48\over x^2}$.

This is because ${3-48\over x^2} = {3\over x^2}-{48\over x^2}$.

Clearly, $3\ne {3\over x^2}$.

Since $x^2 \ne 0$, ${3x^2-48\over x^2} = 0$ can be simplified to ${3x^2-48 = 0. x^2 = 0}$.

The solution would then be $x =\,\, ^+_-\,\, 4 $.